# (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url)) works fine with uwp but not on android

Tags: c#, forms, url, xamarin

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
using (HttpResponseMessage response = awaitclient.GetAsync(url))
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<customlistitems>>(result);
    return list;
}
```

I am on Xamarin Cross Platform. All my code is on pcl. I have a button that, when clicked, gets data from a wcf service showing it on a listview.

It is working on uwp as a charm, but when running on Android it is not able to resolve the url as I analysed.

Should i put some permissions on the Android Manifest to access wcf hosted on my iis or local vs?

I am testing this on my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and the breakpoint is hitting on the line below

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = awaitclient.GetAsync(url))
```

Comment: Is the Url https?

Comment: its http not https this is it on iis http://192.168.5.125:80/CarRental/Service1.svc/rest/getclasses even if i put the one hosted by vs i got th same http://192.168.5.125:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RentACarWeb.ServiceLibrary/Synchronization/rest/getclasses

Comment: are you sure the phone is on the same network as your computer.  192. is a local address if the phone is not connected to wifi on the same network it wont be available

Comment: yes it is on the same network,, and i tell you it works only one time and then it throws unhandeled exception like this photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZWDY.png P.S the photo from google

Comment: @Immortal please make sure you have an internet permission https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Comment: my service is hosted locally why internet connection , besides i enabled internet connection from android manifest  ,i am wondering if there is s a permission should i give to android without pcl

Answer (score 0):

Add the internet permission on the Android Manifest.

[image]

Comment: i did, no way..besides its a local service, and if i upload the service on the internet then the mobile consume it successfully , i just want to test the service while its hosted offline on my labtop